# How would I format inputted minutes/seconds into datetime.now() format?

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, time, python-3.2

I have created a program which requires the user to input a given `TimeType` (`Seconds/Minutes`) and an `objectivetime` (`integer`) (e.g. if the user inputs Seconds and then 5, then the objective time is 5 Secs). In addition, the program also checks the time at the start and then checks the time after to work out the `elapsed_time`. I then wanted to check if the `elapsed_time` is more than or equal to the `objective time`. The code i have written is shown below (minus the other irrelevant code in between `a` and `b`)

```
import time, sys, os, random
a = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
#random code...
b = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
timetype = input("Enter time type: ")#Either Seconds or Minutes
objectivetime = input("Enter objective time: ")#This will be an integer
if timetype == 'Seconds':
    #convert objectivetime to seconds and present in same format as a or b
else:
    #convert objectivetime into minutes and present in same format as a or b
elapsed_time = b-a
if objectivetime<=elapsed_time:
    'Well done'
else:
    'You have exceeded the objective time'
```

Is there any way that the code could be edited to get the objective time to be formatted in the same way as `a` and `b` (start_time and end_time)??

Update--------------------------------------------------------------------------

How would I work out which time is bigger (elapsed_time or objtime)??

See updated code:

```
import time, sys, os, random
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
print(a)
#random code...
time.sleep(3)
b = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
timetype = input("Enter time type: ")#Either Seconds or Minutes
objectivetime = input("Enter objective time: ")#This will be an integer
objectivetime = int(objectivetime) # I noticed you didn't do this in your code
delta = None
if timetype == 'Seconds':    
    delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds = objectivetime)
else:
    delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes = objectivetime)
objtime = a + delta
print(objtime)
#How would I work out which time is greater?? (elapsed_time or objtime)
elapsed_time = b-a
print(elapsed_time-objtime)
```

Comment: It looks like [@Khaelid answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23528388/4279) resolves your first issue: how to convert seconds/minutes given as strings into datetime objects and the second issue: how to compare datetime objects. If you have more issues then you could try to [ask them as separate question(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if they are [on topic on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
objectivetime = int(objectivetime) # I noticed you didn't do this in your code
delta = None

if timetype == 'Seconds':    
    delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds = objectivetime)
else:
    delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes = objectivetime)

objtime = a + delta
```

This will give you a datetime object like `datetime.now()`

To compare the datetime object, you can simply use the comparison operators. For example,

```
b <= objtime # Finished before (or on) the objective time
b > objtime  # Finished after the objective time
```

You don't even need to subtract `a` from `b`! If you still want to, then compare the time deltas instead

```
elapsed_time <= delta # Finished before (or on) the objective time
elapsed_time > delta # Finished after the objective time
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, How would I work out which time is greater between objtime and elapsed_time?

Comment: @HamzahAkhtar: to shows others that the question is answered; you could [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)